# GPUImage build error

Tags: gpuimage

I am trying to use GPUImage, already add the target and build successfully, but when I use it in the viewController and build, there are some problem I can't understand. Anyone know why? Thank you very much.

The code:

```
UIImage *inputImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"1"];

GPUImagePicture *stillImageSource = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:inputImage];
GPUImageSepiaFilter *stillImageFilter = [[GPUImageSepiaFilter alloc] init];

[stillImageSource addTarget:stillImageFilter];
[stillImageSource processImage];

UIImage *currentFilteredVideoFrame = [stillImageFilter imageFromCurrentlyProcessedOutput];


UIImageView *image = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(60, 60, 200, 300)];
image.image = currentFilteredVideoFrame;
[self.view addSubview:image];
[image release];
```

The error:

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/xiaodong/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SilentGif-cuagrzcstwdoemeamjiufacggbfa/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libGPUImage.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): /Users/xiaodong/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SilentGif-cuagrzcstwdoemeamjiufacggbfa/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libGPUImage.a
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GPUImageSepiaFilter", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ThirdViewController-5FAAC33C6210C63D.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Hi There, Did you find a solution??

Comment: @Mc-did you find the solution for this..?if find then please tell me..?I have problem with this.

Answer (score 0):

You can change `Architecture` from `Standard architectures` to `Standard architectures (including 64-bit)` in GPUImage.xcodeproj like this.

[image: project setting]

This is a capability issue, see [this](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage/issues/1433).